# Riak Force remove node from Riak KV cluster

Tags: riak

I have having 5 node cluster of Riak Kv, having ring size as given below

```
riak@172.XX.XX.10  19.9
riak@172.XX.XX.11  19.9
riak@172.XX.XX.12  19.9
riak@172.XX.XX.13  20.0
riak@172.XX.XX.14  20.3
```

but after removing  node

**riak@172.XX.XX.12**  from cluster forcely

by command **sudo riak-admin force-remove -f riak@172.XX.XX.12**

ring size becomes as given below

```
riak@172.XX.XX.10  25.0
riak@172.XX.XX.11  25.0   
riak@172.XX.XX.13  25.0
riak@172.XX.XX.14  25.0
```

but I lossed some data ,  is there any procedure to recover that OR Procedure to remove node from cluster without lossing any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct procedure to remove a node from a riak cluster is described here https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/cluster-operations/adding-removing-nodes/#removing-a-node-from-a-cluster.

The correct procedure from the node that you want remove is:

```
riak-admin cluster leave
riak-admin cluster plan
riak-admin cluster commit
```

In this way the data are migrated from leaving node to the other nodes. The command `riak-admin cluster plan` is not necessary but show the actual pending plan that will be committed with `riak-admin cluster commit` command.

You can also do a similar operation from a different node like this:

```
riak-admin cluster leave <node>
```

where `<node>` is the node name as specified in the node’s configuration files (for example: `riak@192.168.2.1`) and then as before, check and commit plan:

```
riak-admin cluster plan # to see the actual plan
riak-admin cluster commit
```