# Node stuck in LEAVING state after leaving from cluster in Riak

Tags: riak

I have having 5 node cluster of Riak KV on my production, I simply leaving a node from cluster because of some reason but i am **facing issues with status as leaving since last 7 days** how we remove this issues.

I tested for **force-remove** as we all **force-replace** node from cluster Locally  by using command

**`sudo riak-admin force-remove -f riak@172.xx.xx.8`**

and for **force-replace**  I follow this link **`https://gist.github.com/angrycub/4566736`**
but in this case I losses some data.

How do I fix these type of issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `force-remove` command but `riak-admin cluster leave`. See this answer to more details [Riak Force remove node from Riak KV cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292621/riak-force-remove-node-from-riak-kv-cluster/46744305#46744305) .